# How to deal with different size of input and output in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I hope to pick some items(not all of them) from the input data in CUDA.
My input array `d_in` size is 53*53 which is (sorry it is long):

```
$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
z$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
yz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
xyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
wxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
vwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstu
uvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrst
tuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrs
stuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqr
rstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopq
qrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnop
pqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmno
opqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn
nopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
mnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijkl
lmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk
klmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghij
jklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdef
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
wxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
vwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
uvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrst
tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqrs
stuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopqr
rstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnopq
qrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmnop
pqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmno
opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklmn
nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijklm
mnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijkl
lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghijk
klmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghij
jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefghi
ijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefgh
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdefg
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcdef
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcde
efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abcd
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$abc
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ab
bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$a
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$
```

and I want to pick the last item of each row from the input to my output `d_out`. In this way, the output size should be 53. Here is my code. For coping data of `preSort` to`d_in` and `temp` to `d_out`, allocating memory for two pointers and launching kernel.

```
//variables declared
const int ARRAY_BYTES_IN = CAPACITY * sizeof(char);
const int ARRAY_BYTES_ST = CAPACITY * CAPACITY * sizeof(char);
const int CAPACITY = 53;
char preSort[CAPACITY * CAPACITY];
char temp[CAPACITY];

void getLast(){
     //two pointers
     char* d_in;
     char* d_out;

     //allocate gpu memory     
     cudaMalloc(&d_in, ARRAY_BYTES_ST);
     cudaMalloc(&d_out, ARRAY_BYTES_IN);

     //transfer input into gpu
     cudaMemcpy(d_in, preSort, ARRAY_BYTES_ST, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     int size = CAPACITY*CAPACITY;
     int blockSize = 1024;
     int numbBlock = (size + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

     //Launch the kernel
     DoGetLast<<<numbBlock, blockSize>>>(d_out, d_in);

     //Copy back to the  host
     cudaMemcpy(temp, d_out, ARRAY_BYTES_IN, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     cudaFree(d_in);
     cudaFree(d_out);
}
```

the GPU kernel is

```
__global__ void DoGetLast(char* d_out, char* d_in){

     int CAP = 53*53;
     int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

     char f;

     //get the output trmo the input, It's a 1-D array actually, so pick 
     //only one character through every 53 characters from d_in

     if(idx % CAP == (CAP - 1)){
          f = d_in[idx];
          d_out[idx] = f;
     }
}
```

In the main, I only call the `getLast()` method, and using a loop for showing the output.I hope the output will look like:

```
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbazyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba$
```

However, I only got one letter output which is only `z` in my output.
Anyone can tell the problems in my code? and give a help?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/681865

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, Hope it's better than before.

Comment: Read the code in your kernel carefully. Look at the value of CAP. Then ask yourself why you only get one output value. [SO] isn't a trivial mistake spotting service. Don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel has some errors. You should modify your kernel like this.

```
__global__ void DoGetLast(char* d_out, char* d_in)
{
    int CAP = 53; // not 53*53
    int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < CAP * CAP) // d_in boundary check
        if (idx % CAP == (CAP - 1)) {
            char f = d_in[idx];
            d_out[idx / CAP] = f; // not d_out[idx]
        }
}
```

If you had checked your code with [proper CUDA error checking method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/7724939) and `cuda-memcheck` tool, you would have known that your kernel has memory access error and you could have found out what was wrong with your code by yourself.

(If I run your code with `cuda-memcheck`, it says `Invalid __global__ write of size 1` on line `d_out[idx] = f`.)

Also, note that your code has poor level of GPU utilization because out of `numBlock * blockSize` threads you launch, only 53 threads do some work. The rest of them (more than 52 * 53 threads) don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In CUDA, it's preferred to create threads equivalent to output size or less. In your case you should only create 53 thread;

```
 int size = CAPACITY;
 int blockSize = 64;
 int numbBlock = (size + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
```

Now, at the kernel end each thread picks the last item of the row like:

```
__global__ void DoGetLast(char* d_out, char* d_in){

     int idx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
     int CAP = 53;

      if(idx >= CAP)
        return;

     d_out[idx] = d_in[idx*CAP];

}
```